# Angularjs $http service jsonp method keep returning 404 status code

Tags: angularjs, jsonp, angular-http

I encounter an issue with the $http service, while using the jsonp method, I tried to request an html page on another domain. the actual status code response I got was 200, on the other hand the jsonp method keep always returning 404 status code. Does anyone saw this issue before?

After researching I found someone that say if the content of the page is empty it will return a status code -1 or 404 I didn't remember the exact response.

Code:

```
this.$http
        .jsonp(this.$sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://target-domain/landing_page'),
    {
                jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback',
            },
            )
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('sucess', data);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log('error', e);
        });
```

I'm using angularJs 1.6.10

Answer (score 0):

All right I found the reason of this behavior. Since I was requesting an HTML page, which is not in a JSONP format, that leads to not call the provided callback.

Below is the code responsible for this:

```
    if (event) {

    if (event.type === 'load' && !callbacks.wasCalled(callbackPath)) {
      event = { type: 'error' };
    }
    text = event.type;
    status = event.type === 'error' ? 404 : 200;
  }
```

Jquery handle this in better way, I got a status code 200 not 404.